# Parse form using Nokogiri and pass it to URI.encode_www_form?

Tags: ruby, parsing, uri, nokogiri

I have simple HTML form, which I got from a web page:

```
<form id="my">
  inputs....
</form>
```

I need to get this form via it's ID, which I know how to do:

```
@get_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
nb = @get_doc.at_css('#my')
```

maybe could i iterate via object  ?
I need to get all the input values and input names into some variable, and then pass it to `URI.encode_www_form`.

How can I do this? How could I get all the inputs inside the form with names and values, and pass them to `encode_www_form`?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"

Comment: You should almost certainly be using mechanize to do whatever you're doing.

Comment: @theTinMan do you understand everything in this world? why some people are so nervous?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: *WHY* do you want to get the values from a form you got from a page? The values in that form will be the defaults. If you have the defaults, why do you want to encode them? That makes no sense. If you are trying to fill in the form and send it, then you should follow @pguardiario's suggestion.

Comment: @theTinMan i work with automated test's. I need to get filled form data from htnl file, and send this values via net/http lib request to web page, that what i talking about. I need it to be done with nokogiri and net/http. That's all.

Comment: So you have the HTML form pre-populated with default values that you want to send, and that form is stored on disk? If so, saying "it's pre-populated and stored on disk" in the question is very important. Nokogiri has no way of retrieving forms that are filled out by a user, since that action would occur in a browser, which Nokogiri can't access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr = []

# form = doc.at_css '#form'
form.css('input').each do |i|
  arr << [i['name'], i['value']]
end

URI.encode_www_form arr
```

Comment: I tend to use `arr = form.css('input').map { |node| [node['name'], node['value']] }` instead of initializing `arr` to an empty array and then using `each`. It's a little shorter and more direct.